# Удаление дубликатов из таблицы

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток всем!
Возникла такая необходимость как почистить записи в бд от дубликатов.
например от такого:

```
52742231006,Хилс 2310 IB кон.д/собак  Курица/Овощи 363г.
52742341705,Хиллс 3227 IB кон.дсобак Индейка/Овощи 363г
52742231006,Хилс 2310 IB кон.д/собак  Курица/Овощи 363г.
52742419909,Хиллс 4199 NB сух.д/кошек Тунец/Овощи 2кг
52742419909,Хиллс 4199 NB сух.д/кошек Тунец/Овощи 2кг
```

Основная полезная информация это

1. Штрих-код
2. Наименование позиции
   Остальное мета информация Дата создания, рейтинг, единица измерения и прочее.
   Айдишников нет.

Для поиска дубликатов использую следующую конструкцию
`SELECT barcode, product_name, count(product_name) FROM barcodes_catalog GROUP BY barcode, product_name HAVING count( * ) > 1;`

В результате получаю вывод такого вида

```
52742231006,Хилс 2310 IB кон.д/собак  Курица/Овощи 363г.,3
52742341705,Хиллс 3227 IB кон.дсобак Индейка/Овощи 363г,3
52742419909,Хиллс 4199 NB сух.д/кошек Тунец/Овощи 2кг,3
52742526607,Корм для кошек Хилс курица овощи 300 г,3
52742526805,Корм для кошек Хилс тунец овощи 300 г,3
```

Перелопатив большое количество примеров и заглянув в доку, к сожаления не нашел варианта решения задачи.
Заранее большое СПАСИБО за любую информацию и уделенное время =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Добавьте синтетический первичный индекс:

```
ALTER TABLE barcodes_catalog ADD COLUMN id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

2. Удалите дубликаты:

```
DELETE t1
FROM barcodes_catalog t1
JOIN barcodes_catalog t2 USING (barcode)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id;
```

3. Удалите созданный синтетический первичный индекс и создайте естественный по `barcode`:

```
ALTER TABLE barcodes_catalog DROP COLUMN id, ADD PRIMARY KEY (barcode);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4531955e99f33e8012b259d4c54641a)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, единственное я USING (barcode) сделал по двум полям баркоду и продукт нейму